# Wave Particle duality because of discrete time?

Tags: spacetime, time, wave-particle-duality, discrete

If time is discrete, such as the Planck's length, would the transition from one frame of time to the next explain why it appears matter changes from a particle to a wave? During that infinitely small space between each frame we can not measure the particle and it appears as a wave?

Comment: your phrasing implies that the wavelength of the "wave" you suppose would be on the Planck scale. Data tells otherwise. Look at this electron interference pattern http://www.hitachi.com/rd/portal/research/em/doubleslit-f2.html . the planck length is of order 10^_35 meters, way off the scale of the pattern's scale http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_sc.ale

Comment: Ok point taken, but what I was trying to imply was that in between time frames particles appear as waves. Only because there is no discreet space/time.

Comment: If time is discrete, then I don't see why time or motion should be called infinitely small. You can only judge about a distance between two frames if you have a metric e.g. given by an underlying smooth structure.